# Android Navigation Component not working with Dialog Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-navigationview

**Disclaimer:** I've checked the documentation and since `2.1.0` the navigation components has supported Dialog Fragments. (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.1.0)

## Error That I'm Getting

I'm getting this error when trying to go from a `DialogFragment` to my `Start Destination`:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment PostDistressDialog{829f5d1} (bbbc4926-684b-491b-9772-e0f0ffebe0af)} not associated with a fragment manager.`

`PostDistressDialog` is a `DialogFragment` called from `JournalEntryFragment`(can be seen in map below) using the navigation component. `PostDistressDialog` is not an inner class of `JournalEntryFragment`. It is in a class of its own extending `DialogFragment`

## Picture of my Navigation Graph

[image]

## Function Calling NavController

```
public class PostDistressDialog extends DialogFragment implements ISaveDatabase {

...

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (getArguments()!=null) {

        ...

        // Set up the Alert Dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.distressed_levels);
        alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.distressed_how_feel_post);

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        View layout = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.dialog_seekbar, null);
        alertDialog.setView(layout);
        
        ....
        // Add okay button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.okay, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // Save post distress value in Journal Entry
                mJournalEntry.setPostDistress(mTempDistressValue);

                // Save to Journal Entry to database
                // Check if journal entry empty
                if(isJournalEntryEmpty(mJournalEntry)){
                   ...
                }
                else{
                    // Give title if empty
                    if(mJournalEntry.getTitle().isEmpty()) {
                        ....
                    // Save to database
                    new SaveDatabase(getContext(),PostDistressDialog.this).execute(mJournalEntry);
                }

                // Go to main menu
            }
        });

        return alertDialog.create();
    }

    return null;
}

...

@Override
public void databaseSavingCompleted(){
    NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(PostDistressDialogDirections.postDistressDialogToJournalListAction());
}
```

}

Where `this` is `public class PostDistressDialog extends DialogFragment`

## Dialog in my Navigation XML File

```
<dialog
    android:id="@+id/postDistressDialog"
    android:name="com.dgrullon.cbtjourney.dialogs.PostDistressDialog"
    android:label="PostDistressDialog" >
    <argument
        android:name="postDistressDialogArguments"
        app:argType="com.dgrullon.cbtjourney.pojo.JournalEntries"/>
    <action
        android:id="@+id/postDistressDialog_to_journalListAction"
        app:destination="@id/journalList"
        app:popUpTo="@id/journalList"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
</dialog>
```

Comment: "not associated with a fragment manager" means your Fragment is no longer attached to the FragmentManager. Where are you calling `NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @ianhanniballake. I edited my answer to show more of my `DialogFragment`s code. I am calling `NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)` inside another `AsyncTask` class inside of its `onPostExecute()` method. Doesn't Navigation Components do away with fragment managers and Navigation Components 'manage' all the fragments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AlertDialog automatically dismisses the Dialog (and hence, removes your `DialogFragment`) when the callback you add to `setPositiveButton` is fired. Because you're doing work asynchronously, your `databaseSavingCompleted` method is called after the DialogFragment is destroyed, detached from the FragmentManager, and removed from the NavController - you're leaking a reference to your DialogFragment (as it would otherwise be garbage collected).

Therefore when `NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)` fires, all hooks that would let it access the `NavController` are already cleaned up.

If you don't want your button to immediately dismiss the dialog, you need to pass in `null` to `setPositiveButton()` and instead get a reference to the button after the dialog has been created by calling its `getButton()` API and manually setting an `OnClickListener` that would kick off your `AsyncTask` (and disable the button to prevent it from being clicked more than once).